# Threejs: Rotate sphere(globe) to another point(city) on the sphere itself

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm building a globe(sphere geometry) with set of predefined locations on geo-mapped and drawn as point(sphere geometry). I would like to focus(moving one location to another) those locations by rotating globe along y-axis. I tried the following code, seems not working for all locations.

```
location.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.subVectors( location.geometry.boundingBox.max, location.geometry.boundingBox.min );
position.multiplyScalar( 0.20 );
position.sub( location.geometry.boundingBox.min );
location.matrixWorld.multiplyVector3( position );
var point1 = scene.clone().position;
var point2 = position;
var distance = point1.distanceTo( point2 );
locationCollection.rotation.y = distance;
```

I think, I don't understand the concept enough. Hopefully, I will get some idea from the community.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senthanal/j7mda/25/)

Comment: Could you create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) to show a working version of your code?

Comment: I have created fiddle. Bit more code. I have written some short comments for code blocks. Hopefully, it fulfils the purpose. Here follows the fiddle link,  http://jsfiddle.net/senthanal/j7mda/25/

Answer (score 2):

```
var c = group.rotation.y;
var d = -b * (Math.PI / 180)%(2 * Math.PI);
var e = Math.PI / 2 * -1;
group.rotation.y = c % (2 * Math.PI);
group.rotation.x = a * (Math.PI / 180) % Math.PI;
group.rotation.y= d+e;
```

where a= latitude, b= longitude,group=Object3D(or sphere)

Comment: ask it if any confusion?

Comment: You can change group to scene as well, if you were not using group.

Comment: I'm confused why you are setting group.rotation.y twice